# Build custom Reports for Clients using Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have several clients who I get "Leads" to . I am looking to develop an application ( which is part of my site) which displays "Client analytics" .This analytics include the no. of visitors by source etc .

I use Google analytics to track my data .I was wondering of the Google analytics API would be a good way to do this .I tried looking for any example sites or tutorials that use the API to build custom reporting .I am not sure if I am on the right track

Answer (score 0):

I think a simpler way might be using an [embedded Google Data Studio report](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7450249?hl=en) on your site. This will save you time from using the API.